# Pyside2 32 bit arm Linux

Tags: python, linux, arm, 32-bit, pyside2

I am trying to cross compile Qt for Python(PySide2) for my 32-bit ARM Linux system(target) from my Ubuntu 16.04 PC(host). I have built Qt 5.12 for the target and using the tool chain for cross-compilation. I would like to know whether it is even possible since https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python mentions there is not support for 32-bit arm.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the official discussion on this matter in the following [JIRA task](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-802), but it should be possible.

On-device builds work perfectly, so I expect them to also work cross-compiling.

I have been trying to cross-compile it to ARMv7, hopefully I can generate a recipe that could easily be adapter to to other ARM architectures.

Remember that besides building Qt, you will also need to build [Clang 6](https://releases.llvm.org/6.0.0/) since it's necessary for the binding generation process.

After having Qt and Clang, you can just follow the usual [build instructions for PySide2](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python/GettingStarted/X11).

Comment: Thank You. When you mentioned recipe do you mean bitbake recipe?

Comment: I am trying currently trying to cross-compile PySide2 from my X86_64 Ubuntu PC to IMX.6

Comment: I was referring to just having a step-by-step guide of how to do it. At the moment I'm also trying from a X86_64 linux machine to ARMv7.

Comment: Cool. Let me know if you have made any progress. I am currently trying to cross compile PyQt5-5.11.3 using Yocto project.